# Using Opera, Safari, Brave with playwright

Tags: python, testing, playwright

I'm trying to use various browsers for my tests, as long as I know, playwright has a browser called webkit which could be the equivalent to Safari and Opera but, is there a way to actually run Safari and other browsers instead of webkit?

For Chrome and Edge I only had to add *chanel="msedge"*(or chrome) in the line
*browser = playwrights.chromium.launch(channel='msedge', headless=False)* for it to open edge, is there something similar for Opera, Safari, etc.? Or there is another way to use those browsers for the test? I can't find the answer in their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playwright will work with proprietary Chromium-based browsers (including Opera, Edge, Chrome etc.), you can install the browser independently from Playwright and then pass path to its executable via `execuable_path` launch option:

```py
browser = playwrights.chromium.launch(executable_path='/opt/path_to_opera_bin')
```

For automating WebKit and Firefox Playwright currently requires remote debugging protocol which is only available in the custom builds.